# Use a HyperlinkedIdentityField with a non-id primary key on the model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a relatively simple Django 1.7model that represents a server:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    puppetInfo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I intend to expose this information via the the Django REST framework and have created the following serializer and viewset:

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="server-detail", read_only=True)
    instances = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='instance-detail', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Server

class ServerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    lookup_field = "server_hostname"
```

I have tried a number of permutations to get this working but no matter what I try I always get the following error when I access the service:

ImproperlyConfigured at /api/servers/

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "server-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

I am also using the simple router for configuring the URL's:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
....
router.register(r'servers', server.ServerViewSet)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After playing around now for quite some time I think I might have an idea. Do any of your hostnames contain characters that might not be supported by the auto-generated `DRF` url pattern? I managed to fail an example as soon as one of the values in lookup fields contained a dot, e.g. `foobar.com`. As long as none of them had one I didn't get the exception. Not much, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: It was a combination of both this answer and using a regex on the lookup field, this fixed the issue.